# Does the qt-thread share the static global variable or not?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5, mutex

I want to know about how to share the static global variable with qt-thread.

I have a one static global pointer **test_mem** which is shared between qt-thread & main thread.qt-thread with initialize this pointer variable to the starting address of the data memory location which i has to read.then main thread will use the same global variable to read the data from the memory location where this pointer is pointing. But it seems like qt-thread is not sharing the global pointer with main thread.

```cpp
void run() {
    test_mem = (unsignedchar*)mmap(NULL,lenth,PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ,MAP_SHARED,trigger_fd,offset);
    emit pass_test(&test_mem);       
}
```

I want to know about can we share the static global variable between qt-thread & main thread?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve].  As it stands there's not nearly enough information to be able to reproduce/diagnose the problem.

Comment: https://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Answer (score 0):

Qt and C++ in general share the `static` variables.

example of use:

```cpp
//Class where data is stored:

class SharedData {
    static QMutex sMutex;
    static unsigned char* spDataPointer;
    signals: void pass_test(unsigned char** address);
}

//Access from from thread:

SharedData::spDataPointer = (unsignedchar*) mmap(NULL, lenth, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, trigger_fd, offset);
emit SharedData::pass_test(&SharedData::spDataPointer);
```

But there is another approach for your implementation.

You don't need to use a shared variable, just use Qt Signals and Slots:

Connect a `slot` to your `pass_test` `signal` by `Qt::QueuedConnection`.
Like this, when you initialize your pointer, just emit the signal to send it to main-thread. The main-thread will receive your pointer handle it safely.

For more information about QThread show [this article](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html).
For more information about Qt Signals and Slots show [this article](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).

Comment: can this will work ? emit pass_to_main(test_mem)      Inside main->           connect(thread_variable,signal(pass_to_main(*p),SLOT(display(*p),this,Qt::QueuedConnection) ??

Comment: Yes, it will work fine.
Cause the threads share the same address space. `*p` (address of `p`) will be accessible by all threads in the same process (app).

Comment: With `QThread` you can use void `QThread::exit(int returnCode)`.

Comment: Can any-body tell be which is the safe way to terminate the pthread if user want to abort the execution of the pthread, pthread_cancel or pthread_kill ??

Comment: `pthread_cancel` is the safest for terminating a thread since the thread is only supposed to be affected when it has set its cancelability state to true using `pthread_setcancelstate()`.

Comment: `pthread_cancel()` : used to terminate a thread, based on cancel ability state the cleanup handlers are called if any handlers are registered before invoking the thread destructor.
[for more details](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html)

Comment: `pthread_kill()` : used just like `kill()`, it raises a signal to thread. It is possible that some times it affects the entire process like when passed `SIGKILL` to `pthread_kill` will terminate the entire process. [for more details](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html)